# Change CSS settings of a page before page changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile for my mobile application. before I changing a page I want to make some CSS changes on that page. When I am setting for example adding class to id of the next page,or color change: `$("#divA1").css("background-color","blue");`

It change the same `id` on the current page (if it exist) and only then change next page. How can I set my `CSS` settings while on one page but load the next page with those `CSS` settings.

Comment: Are you missing the `#` in your selector? `$("#divA1")`

Comment: `.css(propertyName)` will only read the value of the style.

Comment: Only read the value? it's changes the background color.

Comment: `.css(propertyName)` will only read the style value and this is the example you gave in your question. I was trying to point out a bug in your write up. To set a value, you need to use `.css(propertyName, value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most scenarios, jQuery Mobile loads additional pages into the DOM via ajax calls. This is a fairly fundamental part of how it works and you should insure that all markup IDs across all pages are unique.

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="myContent1"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="myContent2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If your pages contain similar sub-componants, consider a class instead:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="myContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="myContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Classes allow for selection such as `$("#page1.myContent").css("background-color");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but I would suggest you using an asynchronous ajax call to download the DOM of the next page.

Then you can apply the changes you want to that DOM, and finally you plug it into your current DOM.

An stub for that woul look like this:

```
$.ajax('path/to/next/page', {
  async : true,
  complete : function ajaxCallback(newSite) {
    $item = $('YOURSELECTOR');
    // Here you can make changes, such as CSS edition
    $item.css({'background-color' : '#FF0000'});
    // Since you want to make changes to the new site only if you did them in the first site...
    if ($item.length > 0) {
      $(newSite).find('YOURSELECTOR').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000'});
    }

    // Here you can append the new site to the DOM

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it must be on a new page, you have three options.

1. You can pass a variable in the URL to test on the new page and change the CSS appropriately. eg. www.url.com?newcolor=f00
2. You can put a hidden form on the current page, update the values in it and pass it when you go to the next page. (Ugly way to do it but it works.)
3. Set a cookie. (My preferred solution, works great as long as cookies are enabled. Which, honestly, they may not be.)

However, the best option, especially on a mobile device is to keep the current framework of the page and get new content via ajax and load it into a content div on the current page.